# strange segmentation fault error using nstimer

Tags: ios, nstimer

When my app enters backgroud I deactivate all the timers in my app. Actually it is just one timer. I do this the following way:

```
- (void) invalidate_timer {
    if( self.timer != nil ) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil; <-- App crashes on this line
    } 
}
```

But the app sometimes (not always) crashes on the following line. I'm totally confused... How is that possible?

The error is: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1 , 0xeblablabla ;) )

EDIT:

```
- (void) invalidate_timer {
    if( self.timer != nil ) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        //self.timer = nil; <-- doing this, and the app no longer crashes
    } 
}
```

How crazy is this???

EDIT 2:
This is the top part of the stacktrace:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31985848 __kill + 8
1   BlackLane2                      0x0015f85e fatal_signal_handler (PLCrashSignalHandler.m:103)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3408d7e6 _sigtramp + 42
3   BlackLane2                      0x0013b586 -[FutureTourDetailsVC invalidate_timer] (FutureTourDetailsVC.m:159)
```

Comment: Sounds like the timer was released and you are operating on garbage or a different object. Maybe you scheduled with repeats:NO and the timer was already automatically invalidated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the `NSTimer class reference` about the `invalidate` method. It's wrong to set the timer to nil, the run loop takes care about the release.